# Loading Yelp Kaggle DataSet on Google Colab Taking too Long

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory

I am having difficulty loading the Yelp Dataset downloaded from Kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/yelp-dataset/yelp-dataset

I downloaded the zip file from Kaggle directly into my local drive under my Desktop folder and extracted all the files from it.

I was able to upload 4 out of the 5 JSON files from the extracted folder. But there was one that was not able to be uploaded at all (taking forever to upload):

yelp_academic_dataset_review.JSON

For some reason, this file is way too large to upload to Google Colab and the file size is around 7 GB.

I also tried uploading the file from my Google Drive as well.

Is there a way around this?

I couldn’t even read the data from this JSON file since I couldn’t upload it.

I tried this code:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Problem after is nothing happens for hours on end and the data never loads.

Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: Instead of downloading it locally, you can use API Token to get it directly. See here for more [information](https://www.kaggle.com/general/74235).

Comment: Ok I was able to upload the JSON files on Google Colab and mount the files from Google Drive. Now I have a problem reading JSON files in the same file: yelp_academic_dataset_review.JSON. Every time I read the JSON file even with chunking I get memory error